# How to recognize port type of cisco switch via SNMP?

Tags: cisco, snmp, sfp

I would like to filter just copper ports with snmp walks from a Cisco 2960 L2 switch.
I already searched the Cisco SNMP Mibs but I did not found anything if the port is a copper or SFP port.

ifType (1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3) is 6 (Ethernet) whether copper or SFP port.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are also copper SFP modules. I think you mean copper or fiber.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this information from the ifMauType which returns a value from [this list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ianamau-mib/ianamau-mib)

This is defined in the MAU-MIB from [RFC4836](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4836#page-10)

Comment: I can't receive this information. ifMauType is OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.26.2.1.1.3
When I start a snmp walk it starts with OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.1 (ifMIB).

See the following output of SNMPWALK.EXE:
snmpwalk.exe -r:10.xx.xx.xx -c:public -os:1.3.6.1.2.1.26.2.1.1.3

OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.1, Type=OctetString, Value=Vl1
OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.132, Type=OctetString, Value=Vl132
OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.5001, Type=OctetString, Value=Po1
OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.5179, Type=OctetString, Value=StackPort1
OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.5180, Type=OctetString, Value=StackSub-St1-1